# How do you drop an undo file from MySQL cluster?

Tags: mysql

I was hoping someone had an answer for an issue I'm having with MySQL Cluster. Let's say you do this:

```
ALTER LOGFILE GROUP lg1
ADD UNDOFILE 'undofile1.dat'
INITIAL_SIZE 63995904
ENGINE=ndbcluster;
```

and then  you realize you made a mistake (say, with the initial_size setting) and want to either modify the initial size setting for undofile1.dat or even better, drop the new undo file entirely.

How do you do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one seems to know how (it's possible there's no implemented way to do this).

What I used as a workaround was to dump the current data into a file, edit the dumpfile to modify/take out the creation of the undo file in question then re-import afterwards.

It's not perfect, and it might not be a viable approach in some cases, but it worked.